# Get the value of the <select> directly above a clicked button

Tags: jquery, closest

I'm trying to get the value of a `<select>` when a button is clicked. The `<select>` is directly about the button in the DOM, and I'm trying to use `.closest()`

My source is -

```
<div class="alignleft actions">
    <select id='bulk-action-selection' name='bulk-action'>
        <option value='-1' selected='selected'>Bulk Actions</option>
        <option value="delete" >Delete</option>
        <option value="open" >Open Polls</option>
        <option value="close" >Close Polls</option>
        <option value="recast_allow" >Allow Recasting</option>
        <option value="recast_deny" >Prevent Recasting</option>
        <option value="votes_show" >Show Votes</option>
        <option value="votes_hide" >Hide Votes</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="doaction" class="button-secondary action" value="Apply"  />
</div>
```

and the code that I am attempting to use is (returnin 'undefined' -

```
$('#doaction').click(function(e){
    action = $(e).closest('select').val();
});
```

Please help in getting the code to work (or suggesting better ways to go about it). Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your function like so:

```
$('#doaction2').click(function(e){
    action = $(this).prev('select').val();
    // or action = $('#bulk-action-selection2').val();
})
```

`e` is the event, not the reference to the element you clicked (and your button id is `#doaction2`)

Comment: Bro you are missing closing bracket `)` :) just for FYI

Comment: thank you. my keyboard misses a lot of characters and often makes typos. I need to change it :)

Comment: Thank you - I didn't think `.prev()` was appropriate in this scenario, but obviously I was wrong!! No working well.

Comment: consider to get a reference to your select using the id (as I commented on the code)

Comment: @F.Calderan my keyboard "contoured" would highly recommend `:)` http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/ +1 anyways for your reply!

Comment: @Tats_innit I was joking, actually the problem of my keyboard is just the user sitting in front of it :)

Comment: The reason for not being able to use your `// or` suggestion - I actually have two buttons, with identical dropdowns above them (top and bottom of table), so the `.click()` event with become `$('#doaction, #doaction2').click()`. This is why I need to go off of the click, as opposed to using the ID (and why there was the mix up with `#doaction2` - I copied the wrong bit of source by mistake!). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`e` inside `click` is referring to `event` object, I think you mean `$(this)`. Also, you are targetting wrong button, the id you are looking for is `doaction2`

Also, not sure if this is a typo, but you need an extra `)` after `$('#doaction').click()`:

```
$('#doaction2').click(function(e){
    action = $(this).prev('select').val();
}); // <-- this
```

But since you have already assigned an `ID` to the select element, might I suggest you to just target it directly:

```
$('#doaction2').click(function(e){
    action = $('#bulk-action-selection2').val();
});
```

This way whenever your HTML changes, you still get correct behavior.

Comment: Thank for the explaination in the differnece between `e` and this `this`, I thought they were the same. And the typo has been corrected!

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
$('#doaction')
```

should be

```
$('#doaction2')
```

**Full Code**

```
$('#doaction2').click(function(e){
    action = $(e.target).prev('select').val();
});
```

Comment: I have two buttons, I simply copied the wrong source by mistake, but they both exist (and the `.click()` event works fine on both). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() { 
  $('#doaction2').click(function(e){
    action = $('#doaction2').prev().val();
    console.log(action);

  });
});
```